# Get Checked Box List text

Tags: c#

Hi I want to save Checked List Box value(text) in a Variable. How can I do this?

```
     private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        int a = checkedListBox1.;
        checkedListBox1.Hide();
        label1.Text = a.ToString() ;

    }
```

Comment: Post the code, not a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try below code.

```
List<string> checkedItems = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            checkedItems.Add(item.ToString());

        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
            checkedItems.Add(checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString());
        else
            checkedItems.Remove(checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString());

         StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string item in checkedItems)
        {
             builder.Append(item).Append("|");
        }
       label1.Text = builder.ToString();
```